# Consecutive Tail-Tail or Tail-Head

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If A and B play a game with a fair coin such that A wins by getting consecutive TT for the first time, while B wins by getting a consecutive TH.  Who has higher probability of winning the game?

I tried the following method but not sure:

For A to win,

> TT, HTT, HHTT ... that is, 2<sup>-k</sup> for each game length k

For B to win,

> TH, HTH, HHTH ... that is, 2<sup>-k</sup> for each game length k

So ultimately I am getting same probability of each to win.

Comment: @DonThousand Not true. for instance, HT has a probability of $75\%$ to appear before TT (basically, as long as the first two throws aren't TT, HT will come first).

Comment: So, they toss the same coin? Or each is tossing her own coin, with A starting first?

Comment: @Arthur what did you just explain to DonThousand

Comment: @JimmyR "a game with **a** fair coin" seems to imply that there is a single coin, and whoever has their sequence appear first wins.

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty He thought that just because they are two equally long sequences, they are equally likely to appear first. But that argument is flawed, as is evidenced by my example.

Comment: @JimmyR. It was my mistake in understanding the problem. You can remove your downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first T happens, none of them have won yet, and on the next throw after the first T, one of them will win. If that next throw is a T, then A wins, and if it's a H then B wins. That makes it the same probability for either of them to win.

Comment: are you sure because even I have tested with all possible combinations upto game length 5 but still can't generalise.

Comment: However these two answers [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534800/probability-that-a-need-more-coin-tosses-to-get-two-consecutive-heads-than-b?rq=1] confused me

Comment: And this one too [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450884/fair-coin-tosses-until-until-two-consecutive-heads-or-two-consecutive-tails-appe?rq=1]

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty The game will start with $k$ times $H$, then a $T$ (and both players hold their breath) and then a decisive throw that has equal chance to be in favor of $A$ and of $B$. Here $k$ is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: @drhab Got it, thank you!